# SQL - Left Join and Group By causes row data from second table to get mixed up

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables, the first table has a reference to the id from the second table, I want to make a query involving a left join with fields from the second table as well as with a COUNT function in the select, because of the COUNT function, I am using an GROUP BY clause.

So my query looks something like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.txt, t2.id, t2.txt, COUNT(t2.id) 
FROM test_data1 t1 
LEFT JOIN test_data2 t2 ON (t1.ref_col = t2.id) 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

In my tables, only the second row of test_data1 has an entry in ref_col, so I would expect that for the first row in the results, the value for t2.id would be NULL, however that is not the case (in my example I see the value 2, but I'm not sure if there might be an element of randomness here).

If I use

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id), MAX(t1.txt), MAX(t2.id), MAX(t2.txt), COUNT(t2.id) 
FROM test_data1 t1 
LEFT JOIN test_data2 t2 ON (t1.ref_col = t2.id) 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I get my expected results, however I am surprised this is necessary given that there will at most only be one entry in test_data2 matching ref_col in test_data1.

Does anyone know why LEFT JOIN + GROUP BY is behaving this way? This is using MySQL version 8 on Linux.

If you want to reproduce this here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data1 (id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                         txt VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
                         ref_col int unsigned DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE test_data1 (id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                         txt VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
                         ref_col int unsigned DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO test_data1 (id, txt, ref_col) 
VALUES 
(1,'zz',NULL), 
(2,'yy',2), 
(3,'xx',NULL);

INSERT INTO test_data2 (id, txt) 
VALUES 
(1,'aa'), 
(2,'bb'), 
(3,'cc'), 
(4,'dd');
```

Comment: I do not see the diference between the outputs: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1cf0f968be6e100a33b521caf924fa5) (aliases for output columns added).

Comment: So I ran things fresh to double-check and for the first row I got (1,'zz',4,NULL,0) which is different than the (1,'zz',NULL,NULL,0) that is in the fiddle (and which is what I expected). If I run the select query a second time the values for the first row become (1,'zz',2,NULL,0) which is very strange. I'm starting to think this might be a platform specific bug or something like that. I just tried it out on Windows, and I get the same results as the fiddle. My full version string, if you are curious, is "Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"

Comment: I think the issue might be the same as this bug fixed in 8.0.21, which is annoying but at least my understanding of sql is not fundamentally flawed - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99398